# How to to make a varargs statement in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

In javascript I am in situation where i need to make variable arguments based on a length of an array, below is an sample code

```
function getValesList(json){
    return getValues(json[0])+getValues(json[1])+getValues(json[2]);
}

function getValues(json1){
    let valueList = Object.values(json1);
    let valueListPipe = valueList.join("|");
    return valueListPipe+lineSeparator;
}
```

where json is an array of JSON objects and I need to make a pipe delimiter file based on the length of incoming array. How to make it dynamic where I can do like a varargs in JAVA

Answer (score 0):

If you're just passing N arguments of the same type, you can use the `rest` feature of Javascript for function arguments.

```
function getValuesList(...json){
    return json.map(j => getValues(j)).join("");
}
```

This allows you go pass any number of separate arguments as in `getValuesList(o1, o2, o3, o4)` and the `json` parameter within your function will automatically be an array of however many arguments were passed.